# Format unstructured string

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have tried several methods (by position, by white space, regex) but cannot figure how to best parse the following lines as a table. For e.g. let's say the two lines I want to parse are:

```
Bonds               Bid   Offer  (mm)   (mm) Chng
STACR 2015-HQA1 M1  125    120    5   x 1.5   0
STACR 2015-HQA12 2M2  265  5   x       -2
```

I want that it should parse as follows for [BondName] [Bid] [Offer]:

```
[STACR 2015-HQA1 M1] [125] [120]

[STACR 2015-HQA12 2M2] [265] [null]
```

Notice the null which is an actual value and also the spaces should be retained in the bond name. FYI, the number of spaces in the Bond Name will be 2 as in the above examples.

**Edit**: Since many of you have asked for code here it is. The spaces between the points can range from 1-5 so I cannot reply on spaces (it was straightforward then).

```csharp
string bondName = quoteLine.Substring(0, 19);
string bid = quoteLine.Substring(19, 5).Trim();
string offer = quoteLine.Substring(24, 6).Trim();
```

The only way I can see this working is that:

- 1st data point is STACR (Type)
- 2nd data point is the year and Series
  (e.g. 2015-HQA1)
- 3rd data point is Tranche (M1)
- 4th data point is bid
  (e.g. 125 ** bid is always available **)
- 5th data point is offer (e.g. 120 ***but can be blank
  or whitespace which introduces complexity***)

Comment: what about splitting on tabs

Comment: Are there always at least 2 spaces between the columns?

Comment: I believe you can iteratively use a string.split on the spaces but if you show some code, it would be easier to demonstrate.

Comment: In case you have `STACR 2015-HQA12 2M2 265 5 x -2` how do you decide `265` is bid or offer?

Comment: @nycdan I have tried that as well but let's take the example of the second record after 265 I dont want the parser to consider 5 as an offer

Comment: @ArghyaC bid is always available it's the offer which could be missing. I should correct my post above.

Comment: Yes, that was misleading. With your updated requirement, you can try my answer (posting in a minute).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the current set of requirements, I'm assuming the following
1. String starts with 3 part bond name
2. Followed by bid
3. Followed by offer (optional)
4. After that, we'll have something like ... x ... ... (we'll use x as reference)

Given they are valid, you can use the following code

```
var str = "STACR 2015-HQA1 M1  125    120    5   x 1.5   0"; //your data
var parts = str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

//we'll use this pattern : <3 part bond name> <bid> <offer/null> <something x ....>
var xIsAt = parts.IndexOf("x"); //we'll use x as reference
if (xIsAt > 2) //first three are BondName
    parts.RemoveRange(xIsAt - 1, parts.Count - xIsAt + 1); //remove "5 x 1.5 ..."
var bond = string.Join(" ", parts.Take(3)); //first 3 parts are bond
var bid = parts.Count > 3 ? parts.ElementAt(3) : null; //4th is bid
var offer = parts.Count > 4 ? parts.ElementAt(4) : null; //5th is offer
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
I did not account for the blank 'Offer' so this method will fail on a blank 'Offer'. Looks like someone already has a working answer, but i'll leave the linq example for anyone that finds it useful.
[END EDIT]

Linq based option.

Split the string by spaces, and remove empty spaces.  Then reverse the order so you can start from the back and work your way forward.  The data appears more normalized at the end of the string.

For each successive part of the line, you skip the previous options and only take what you need.  For the last part which is the long string, you skip what you don't need, then reverse the order back to normal, and join the segments together with spaces.

```
        string test = "STACR 2015-HQA1 M1  125    120    5   x 1.5   0";

        var split_string_remove_empty = test.Split(new char[]{ ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Reverse();

        var change = split_string_remove_empty.Take(1)
                                              .SingleOrDefault();
        var mm2 = split_string_remove_empty.Skip(1)
                                           .Take(1)
                                           .SingleOrDefault();
        var mm3 = split_string_remove_empty.Skip(3)
                                           .Take(1)
                                           .SingleOrDefault();
        var offer = split_string_remove_empty.Skip(4)
                                             .Take(1)
                                             .SingleOrDefault();
        var bid = split_string_remove_empty.Skip(5)
                                           .Take(1)
                                           .SingleOrDefault();
        var bonds = string.Join(" ", split_string_remove_empty.Skip(6)
                                                              .Reverse());
```

Output:
[image: Output data for above code]